# Video player not working on Jelly Bean device :android.content.ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, video, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I recently tried to run my application on `JellyBean` device and was surprised to see that the video player is not working and throws error:

```
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.packagename.pkg/files/Movies/505c5bea-af51-4100-b95a-e2e87e6126c4.mp4 typ=video/* }
```

The same works fine on devices 2.2 till 4.0

The relevant code is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(
                            Uri.parse(type,path), "video/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Can somebody point what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Obvious, but: does this Jellybean device actually have some kind of video player installed? My Nexus 7 didn't by default, for example.

Comment: @nickgrim if i try to record a video from the default camera that playes well. So shdn't the app recorded video also play. Let me know if i am wrong in my understanding.

Comment: Please see my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336925/weird-error-with-video-intent-on-jelly-bean/13348968#13348968